# Country flag of customer on bigcommerce orders page is not appearing?

Tags: web, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

I have created a custom checkout for bigCommerce it's a third party app so I am able to create the customers and orders on the Bigcommerce portal but on the order page the country flag is not showing with the customer. Is there anything I am missing for the for order flag.
And also shipping method is not syncing with the orders.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the geoip_country and geoip_country_iso2 with order parameters the country flag will appear with the orders according to the ip address.